# R adding lagged variable to sarima model

Tags: r, arima

I'm trying to introduced a lagged value of a variable already within my regression and then use an arima model on that new collection of variables. For example, I'm trying to model the relationship between mortality, temperature, and pollution particle levels using the regression of mortality rates on temperature and pollution particle levels. Then, introducing a lagged variable of the particles levels of four weeks prior. Here is the code for this:

```
temp = tempr-mean(tempr)
ded = ts.intersect(cmort, trend=time(cmort), temp, temp2=temp^2, part, partL4=lag(part,-4))
summary(fit <- lm(cmort~trend + temp + temp2 + part + partL4, data=ded))
pairs(ded) # easiest way is to do all of them
cor(ded)
AIC(fit)/nrow(ded) - log(2*pi)
BIC(fit)/nrow(ded) - log(2*pi)
```

Where temp is the centered temperature values, temp2 is the squared centered temperature, part is the level of pollution particles in the air and partL4 is the particle levels of four weeks prior. This regression works as intended and gives me no issues. However, the issues arise when I attempt to use an arima model on this new collection of variables. Here is the code I am using for using an arima model on the original collection of variables without the new lag variable:

```
trend = time(cmort); temp = tempr - mean(tempr); temp2 = temp^2
fit = lm(cmort~trend + temp + temp2 + part, na.action=NULL)
acf2(resid(fit), 52) # implies AR2
sarima(cmort, 2,0,0, xreg=cbind(trend, temp, temp2, part) )
```

This model works as well. However, when I try to introduce the partL4 lagged variable, I receive an error of:

Error in stats::arima(xdata, order = c(p, d, q), seasonal = list(order = c(P, : lengths of 'x' and 'xreg' do not match

When I check the length of cmort and the new collection of variables being used in xreg, the lengths are slightly off. However, when I remove the partL4 variable as it was in the original code, the lengths match.

I'm really lost on how to fix this issue and run the arima model on the new variable collection. The only library that needs to be used is:

```
library(astsa)
```

Any help would be much appreciated, as i'm not sure how to get the lengths to align, or if there is another better way to do this.

Here is my full code as of right now (Gives Error):

```
library(astsa)
temp = tempr-mean(tempr)
temp2=temp^2
trend=time(cmort)
partly=lag(part, -4)

ded = ts.intersect(cmort, trend, temp, temp2, part, partL4, dframe=TRUE)

fit <- lm(cmort~trend + temp + temp2 + part + partL4, data=ded, na.action=NULL)
summary(fit)

attach(ded)
tsplot(resid(fit))
acf2(resid(fit)) #implies AR2


sarima(cmort, 2,0,0, xreg=cbind(trend, temp, temp2, part, partL4))
# pairs(ded) # easiest way is to do all of them
# cor(ded)
# AIC(fit)/nrow(ded) - log(2*pi)
# BIC(fit)/nrow(ded) - log(2*pi)
detach(ded)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem comes from the lag: you're shifting the values in time, so when you call `cbind` on all the time series, you're end up with data that extends beyond the final date for `cmort` and R complains. (Try `cbind(trend, temp, temp2, part, partL4)` and you can see clearly what is happening). If you drop those values from `partL4` before you call `sarima` it should work:

```
partL4_new <- window(partL4, end = 1979.750)
sarima(cmort, 2,0,0, xreg=cbind(trend, temp, temp2, part, partL4_new))
```